# How to migrate away from @zeit/next-sass deprecation?

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, next.js

How can I migrate and change the `next.config.js` file from `@zeit/next-sass` to use Next.js built-in support for Sass?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zeit/next-sass

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS(withSass({
    webpack(config, options) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 100000
                }
            }
        });

        return config;
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

Next.js built-in Sass support requires you to install `sass` as a dependency.

```
$ npm install sass
```

You can then simply remove `@zeit/next-sass` and `@zeit/next-css` plugins from your config.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    webpack(config, options) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 100000
                }
            }
        });

        return config;
    }
};
```

For further details check the [official Sass support docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support).